# angular-ui-router: how to reresolve parent data after a child transitions to parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

The problem is that when I submit the content inside my modal in ui route dashboard.addTask I want ui-router to redirect me back to dashboard and refresh the controller as well as reresolve tasks.

I am able to refresh the controller however for some strange reason tasks are resolved again after the controller is already reinitialized. Even more bizarre is that when I debug it in chrome it works after I submit the form twice.

However when I am outside the debugger it never reresolves tasks but only refreshes the controller and loads the same data.

This is my app.js:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "static/partials/dashboard.html",
        controller: 'TasksController',
        resolve: {
            tasks: ['taskService', function (taskService) {
                return taskService.getTasks();
            }]
        },
        reload: true,
    })
    .state("dashboard.addTask", {
        url: "/add/task",
        onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'static/partials/addTask.html',
                controller: 'AddTaskController'
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function success() {
                //Do success things
            }, function fail(reason) {
                if (~reason.indexOf('backdrop')) {
                    $state.go("dashboard");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is my taskService.js:

```
app.factory('taskService', function ($http, $q, $timeout) {
return {
    getTasks: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/requests/task').success(function(data) { 

            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                data[i].dateModified = moment(data[i].dateModified, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                data[i].duration = (data[i].frequency * 60 * 60) + "s";

                //Works out starting point for colour change.
                data[i].delay = (data[i].dateModified.valueOf() - moment().valueOf())/1000 + "s";
            }
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(msg, code) {
            deferred.reject(msg);
            $log.error(msg, code);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

}
);

This is the relevant part of my modal controller addTaskController.js:

```
scope.ok = function () {
   ...

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: ...,
        url: '/requests/task/'
    }).then(function (response) {

        $state.transitionTo("dashboard", null, {inherit:true, reload: true})
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a third argument in $state.go() that you can use set the ui-sref-options.

`$state.go('stateName', null, {reload:true});`

The second being your state params if you have any.